# Java generics

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to make a method that will take anything, including objects, Integers etc? I have a method checking the value if it is null and I was thinking perhaps it could be done with generics instead of overloading. Unfortunately, trying

```
nullChecking(Class<? extends Object> value){
...
}
```

won't allow Integers as they extend Number not object.
Is there a way?

Cheers

Comment: (Note: Integer extends Number; Number extends Object; extends is essentially transitive.)

Comment: Actually, this won't accept Integers as they don't extend Class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just do `nullChecking(Object value)` ? If you just wanna test if it's null, it will work.

Comment: *slaps forehead* I just listened to a bunch of stuff about generics today so I think I was defaulting to that thinking. Thanks :)

Cheers

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't work on int, char, long,etc. but these cannot be null, so there is no real problem.

Comment: @Vinegar @Bishiboosh: it would work. They'd be autoboxed into Integer, Char, ... and thus always return false ...

Comment: Yes but anyway testing them would be useless, since they can't be null.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do... If it's just checking if a object is `null` then you can simply do this:

```
public static boolean nullChecking(Object obj) {
    return obj == null;
}
```

Comment: Yep I am doing something like this, it is simply to throw an error if it is null so it won't return anything and object fits the bill in this case.

Cheers

Comment: @starblue: I'd expect "ensureNonBlue()" to do something like "if (obj == null) throw new NullPointerException()" or something to the same effect. I wouldn't expect it to simply return some value ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do this, but I wouldn't recommend it for your usage...

So, here is how to do this (and warning, it circumvents compile time type checking, so you open yourself up to run-time class-cast exceptions...)

Say you have a "getter" than can return multiple types - it can be declared as a generic type like so:

```
public <X> X get(String propertyName) { ... }
```

You can do the same for a 'setter':

```
public <X> void set(String property, X value) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

A

```
public <T> boolean isNull(T obj) { return obj == null; }
```

would work... but... what for?

Do you think that

```
if (isNull(myObj)) { ... }
```

is easier to write than

```
if (myObj == null) { .... }
```

?

Consider you will doing a method invocation in the first case and that consumes [almost nothing, but it does] system resources with no logical advantage, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.7 you can use the methods of [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) :

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj)
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj, String message)
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj, Supplier<String> messageSupplier)
```

or just check their code.